# Image Upload to Database Using Base64 Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, base64

I want to upload image to Database in Base64 format using Spring Boot, So I made a table with blob type. I want to upload and retrieve the Image, Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this.

```
  @Controller
            public class ImageUploadController {
            @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImageToDB", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public String uploadImgaeToDB(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile imageFile, Model model) throws IOException {
            byte[] imageArr = imageFile.getBytes(); 

            //Base64 that converts imageâs bytes to 
            //base64 encoded string, and this string store in a 
            //varchar column of database.
            String imageAsString= Base64.encodeBase64String(imageArr);
             //code to store the @code{imageAsString} object 
            // to database}

            //DisplayImageFromDB.jsp
            return "Display_Image";
            } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload an image from the frontend, call the POST method with the multipart request body.

```
@PostMapping("/upload/profile-image")
    public String uploadImgaeToDB(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
        byte[] imageArr = imageFile.getBytes();

        // Create Entity and set profile image.
       User user = new User();
       user.setProfileImage(imageArr);
}
```

Create an entity with below profile image variable like below.

```
@Entity
public class User {
        @Lob
        @Column(name = "profile_image")
        private byte[] profileImage;

        public byte[] getProfileImage() {
            return profileImage;
        }

        public void setProfileImage(byte[] profileImage) {
            this.profileImage = profileImage;
        }
}
```